# Comparing dates using month and year only Access

Tags: ms-access

I want to compare two date fields in an Access query taking into account the month and year only. The first date is an Approval Date and the second date is a Due Date.

If the Approval Date month and year is greater than the Due Date month and year then I want to mark the records as "Late", otherwise I want the records marked as "Not Late".

I have tried using Format([Approval Date],"mmyyyy") for both the Approval Date and Due Date but this turns the field into a string and when I do the comparison logic to mark records as Late, it is not always correct.

Comment: You can simply compare like `IIF([ApprovalDate]>[DueDate],"Late","Not Late")`. Because, if month and year is greater, then date must be greater.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateDiff` as it can compare by calendar month:

```vb
If DateDiff("m", [Approval Date], [Due Date]) > 0 Then
    Message = "Late"
Else
    Message = "Not late"
End If
```